# SUM result doubling in Report Builder 3.0 query to Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I need to get the Total amount of fees in a table without the “Late Fee” and “Filing Fee” and then the total amount of fees including those if they are present while verifying the correct permit ID.  When I try and add the second  fee to the query it doubles the fees.  Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
  PERMIT.CODE,
  PERMIT.ID2,
  PERMIT.ID1,
  PERMIT.ID3,
  SUM(ITEM.FEE) AS TotalFee,
FROM 
  PERMIT,
  ITEM
AND PERMIT.CODE        = ITEM.CODE
AND PERMIT.ID1         = ITEM.ID1
AND PERMIT.ID2         = ITEM.ID2
AND PERMIT.ID3         = ITEM.ID3
AND ITEM.DESC           <> 'Late Fee'
AND ITEM.DESC           <> 'Filing Fee'
```

Which results in correct numbers:

```
TOTALFEE
550
350
```

Yet when I add the second fee to the query:

```
SELECT 
  PERMIT.CODE,
  PERMIT.ID2,
  PERMIT.ID1,
  PERMIT.ID3,
  SUM(ITEM.FEE) AS TotalFee,
  SUM(t.FEE) AS Fee,
FROM 
  PERMIT,
  ITEM,
  ITEM t
AND PERMIT.CODE        = ITEM.CODE
AND PERMIT.ID1         = ITEM.ID1
AND PERMIT.ID2         = ITEM.ID2
AND PERMIT.ID3         = ITEM.ID3
AND ITEM.DESC           <> 'Late Fee'
AND ITEM.DESC           <> 'Filing Fee'
AND PERMIT.CODE        = t.CODE
AND PERMIT.ID1         = t.ID1
AND PERMIT.ID2         = t.ID2
AND PERMIT.ID3         = t.ID3
```

I get the same two rows, but the numbers are off.
Results:

```
TOTALFEE | FEE
1650     | 1650
2100     | 2100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't have a `group by`, which should be the case when you use aggregate functions. Also you can get the desired results using conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT 
 PERMIT.CODE,
 PERMIT.ID2,
 PERMIT.ID1,
 PERMIT.ID3,
 SUM(case when ITEM.DESC <> 'Late Fee' then ITEM.FEE end) AS TotalFee,
 SUM(case when ITEM.DESC <> 'Filing Fee' then ITEM.FEE end) AS Fee
FROM PERMIT JOIN ITEM
ON PERMIT.CODE = ITEM.CODE
AND PERMIT.ID1 = ITEM.ID1
AND PERMIT.ID2 = ITEM.ID2
AND PERMIT.ID3 = ITEM.ID3
GROUP BY PERMIT.CODE, PERMIT.ID2, PERMIT.ID1, PERMIT.ID3
```